# A "moved to chat" comment appears to be a broken link for me but works for others

Tags: discussion, bug, chat

Yesterday I flagged a "moved to chat" comment on [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76631/are-class-features-abilities-and-feats-that-allow-%E2%88%925-to-attack-to-get-10-to-d/76641#76641) answer as the chat it links to gave a page not found error. To my surprise the flag was declined as apparently the chat works fine for others. I am logged in (tried logging out and back in actually) on chat but still getting page not found. Is there another requirement to view old chats that I may be missing?

Comment: The [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36702/discussion-on-answer-by-lino-frank-ciaralli-are-class-features-abilities-and-f) works fine for me.

Comment: @diego That is odd. For me it goes to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36702/discussion-on-answer-by-lino-frank-ciaralli-are-class-features-abilities-and-f and that's a page-not-found. What browser are you on? I'm on firefox

Comment: @diego Just tried it in a fresh chrome install and got the same bad behavior. Very strange

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and your link redirects me to the exact same room

Comment: I just tried it in IE and it did not work until I logged in. Do you get the not logged in banner when you try going there?

Comment: @diego I do appear to be logged in. I tried logging out and back in and am still getting the same not found page. Thinking about how to change this question since it appears to be more of a technical issue than anything to do with policy

Comment: IE11 here, link worked fine for me

Comment: Chrome v.57..... here, no problem seeing the comment-chat room.

Comment: Do other [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) work for you?

Comment: @diego Works perfectly

Comment: Checking in, same situation as Ceribia - Chrome 57.0.2987.98, link to RPG general works fine, link to discussion of Lino's answer is a Page Not Found.

Comment: Looking at some [Meta.SE posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288612/make-chat-room-transcripts-forever-public-if-the-room-was-auto-deleted) it looks like you need a certain rep (I'm guessing 10k based on who can and can't see it [it could be 15k though], but I can't find anything that says exactly) to view deleted rooms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87761/is-there-a-list-of-se-chat-privileges-and-the-minimum-reputation-required-for-t/87773#87773) you need 10k reputation to view frozen/deleted rooms. It looks like neither you, nor any of the other users that can't see this room have at least 10k reputation on any site so you wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: [/facepalm] of course, it's 10K rep to see deleted things, generally. Good catch!